# Domain Masking/Cloaking: Get masked/cloaked URL with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to use javascript to return the masked domain name rather than the actual.

**Masked Name**

www.masked.com

**Real Name of site**

www.real.com

Both window.location.href and document.name return www.real.com

Comment: What is a "masked name"?  What does that mean?  How are you "masking" the domain?  frames?  iframes?  redirects?

Comment: A masked or cloaked domain name. IE real.com is the actual and masked.com is cloaking

Comment: How are you doing this "masking"?  How does it work?  How is it set up?  Did you configure something on your server to do this?  Are you using redirects?  Does it use frames?

Comment: Set up through DNS. Different DNS have different terminology. Currently this application domain is hosted on Dreamhost, within control panel you have option of cloaking another domain. Showing that domain, while displaying the cloaked URL

Comment: There is no such thing as "cloaked domains" in DNS.  Dreamhost is just serving an HTML page with `<frame src="http://www.real.com">`.  http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Add_a_domain#Cloaked

Comment: Ok, cool, so my question still is, is it possible to obtain the www.masked.com

Comment: Probably not.  I'm assuming you have no control over the HTML that Dreamhost creates, so there is no way to get what you want.  The [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) is going to block your frame from talking to the parent page.  You can try `document.referrer`, but I'm not sure if that'll work.

Comment: not through js, no. If it's a different domain (which you've shown) then it violates same domain origin policy. IOW it's cross-site scripting (XSS).

Comment: I think what you mean is to show an URL that is different than the URL of the site.

One way is with iFrames, but there are others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Masking works by using frames.

The domain hosting the frame HTML and the domain hosting your page (loaded in the frame) will be different.

You can't read data (including the location) across origins (for security reasons).